# extract dataframes from list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe

If I have the following object:

```
> str(dat)

'data.frame':   94 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Features:List of 94
  ..$ :'data.frame':    27 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Key  : chr  "CUIVOCABS" "majorType" "minorType" "language" ...
  .. ..$ Value: chr  "CSP,MTH,MSH,OMIM,CST,NCI_NCI-GLOSS,MTHICD9,CHV,NDFRT,ICD10CM,SNOMEDCT_US,NCI,AOD,LCH_NW,NCI_FDA,ICD9CM,LCH,DXP,WHO,COSTAR" "umls" "uncased" "" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    27 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Key  : chr  "scPageRank" "majorType" "scStringSimilarity" "Certainty" ...
  .. ..$ Value: chr  "3.87909E-05" "umls" "1" "5" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    7 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Key  : chr  "rule" "PREF" "CUI" "STY" ...
  .. ..$ Value: chr  "listDiagnosis" "Spasms" "C0037763" "Sign or Symptom" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    26 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Key  : chr  "language" "majorType" "minorType" "query" ...
  .. ..$ Value: chr  "" "umls" "uncased" "elbow" ...
  ..$ :'data.frame':    7 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Key  : chr  "rule" "PREF" "CUI" "STY" ...
  .. ..$ Value: chr  "listDiagnosis" "Subarachnoid Hemorrhage" "C0038525" "Disease or Syndrome" ...
```

I would like to extract each individual data frame, where each contains two columns: Key and Value. I would then like to rbind each of them into one large dataframe.

How do I do this?

If I do `do.call(rbind, dat)` I get:

```
[,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]   [,9]   [,10]  [,11]  [,12]  [,13]  [,14]  [,15]  [,16]  [,17]  [,18] 
Features List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2
         [,19]  [,20]  [,21]  [,22]  [,23]  [,24]  [,25]  [,26]  [,27]  [,28]  [,29]  [,30]  [,31]  [,32]  [,33]  [,34]  [,35]  [,36] 
Features List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2
         [,37]  [,38]  [,39]  [,40]  [,41]  [,42]  [,43]  [,44]  [,45]  [,46]  [,47]  [,48]  [,49]  [,50]  [,51]  [,52]  [,53]  [,54] 
Features List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2
         [,55]  [,56]  [,57]  [,58]  [,59]  [,60]  [,61]  [,62]  [,63]  [,64]  [,65]  [,66]  [,67]  [,68]  [,69]  [,70]  [,71]  [,72] 
Features List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2
         [,73]  [,74]  [,75]  [,76]  [,77]  [,78]  [,79]  [,80]  [,81]  [,82]  [,83]  [,84]  [,85]  [,86]  [,87]  [,88]  [,89]  [,90] 
Features List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2
         [,91]  [,92]  [,93]  [,94] 
Features List,2 List,2 List,2 List,2
```

where I can access each dataframe individually, but I would prefer one large dataframe.

Thanks

Comment: try data.table::rbindlist(dat)

Comment: It's a one column data frame of a list of data frames; try `do.call(rbind, dat$Features)`.  (With a MWE -- `dat <- list(data.frame(key = 1:5, value = 6:10), data.frame(key = 1:10, value = 11:20))` -- `do.call(rbind, dat)` returns what you want.)